# HTML/CSS image change place when window resized

Tags: css, image, window

I am a noob in coding and have a problem. i have an image that is in the right place except when i resize my window. Here is my CSS-code:

```css
img{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 40.47px;
 width: 118.712px;
 height: 118.236px;
 }
```

I hope someone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: can you write full example to know exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your position to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
position:absolute;
```

for your image and then position it on your page with

```
top: some pixels ;
left: some pixels ;
```